# passing data values from inner function to inner function with js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am combining two functions into a single function and need to pass the value of my `id` from `calla()` to `callb()` so `callb()` can also use that information in its AJAX call. When these were two different functions, a button was clicked which triggered my `callb()` function and passed the `id` to it. Now that they are one single function with two calls, I am uncertain how to pass this along.

I know it's going to be some type of event listener but when I wrap `callb()` in a  `jQuery(document).load(` then it tells me `callb()` is undefined. If I remove `callb()` then it doesn't run the function at all.

```js
jQuery(document).on('popup/show', (event, id) => {
  if (id === 123) {
    function callA() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        data: {
          action: 'list_count'
        },
        type: 'post',
        url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
          var id = jQuery().data('id')
          var html = '';
          
          jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
            html += '<div class="accordion-header ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-corner-all" id="' + value.id + '" style="display:table-row">';
            html += '<div class="image"  style="display: table-cell";>' + value.img + '</div>';
            html += '<div style="display: table-cell";>' + value.Name + '</div>';
            html += '<div  style="display: table-cell">' + value.Size + '</div>';
            html += '<div  style="display: table-cell"> ' + value.Number + ' </div>';
            html += '<div class="tdid_' + value.id + '"  style="display: table-cell">' + value.Status + '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div id="cid_' + value.id + '" class="bg_clear ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="display: table-cell">';
            html += '<div class="bg_clear ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="display: table-cell"></div>';
            html += '  </div>';
          });
          jQuery('#list').html(html);
        }
      });
    }

    function callB(id) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
        data: {
          action: 'options_function',
          cid: id
        },
        success: function(data) {
          jQuery(data).after('#cid_' + id)
          console.log(data);
          console.log(id);
        }
      });
    }
    
    callA();
    callB();
  }
});
```

Attempted  alternate code for `function b`

```js
jQuery(document).load(function callB(id) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    data: {
      action: 'options_function',
      cid: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery(data).after('#cid_' + id)
      console.log(data);
      console.log(id);
    }
  });
});

callA();
//  callB();
```

EDIT 1- Add `callb` into the success of `calla`

```
jQuery(document).on('popup/show', (event, id) => {
  if (id === 123) {
    function callA() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        data: {
          action: 'list_count'
        },
        type: 'post',
        url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
          var id = jQuery().data('id')
          var html = '';
          
          jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
            html += '<div class="accordion-header ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-corner-all" id="' + value.id + '" style="display:table-row">';
            html += '<div class="image"  style="display: table-cell";>' + value.img + '</div>';
            html += '<div style="display: table-cell";>' + value.Name + '</div>';
            html += '<div  style="display: table-cell">' + value.Size + '</div>';
            html += '<div  style="display: table-cell"> ' + value.Number + ' </div>';
            html += '<div class="tdid_' + value.id + '"  style="display: table-cell">' + value.Status + '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div id="cid_' + value.id + '" class="bg_clear ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="display: table-cell">';
            html += '<div class="bg_clear ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="display: table-cell"></div>';
            html += '  </div>';
          });
          jQuery('#list').html(html);
            
    function callB(id) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
        data: {
          action: 'options_function',
          cid: id
        },
        success: function(data) {
          jQuery(data).after('#cid_' + id)
          console.log(data);
          console.log(id);
        }
      });
    }
            
            
        }
      });
    }


    
    callA();
   callB();   /* <<<<<<<<<<< tried with this commented out or on, doesnt matter/*
  }
});
```

Edit 2 -
Original button code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="options-btn" class="button" onclick="function callB('+ value.id+')" data-id="'+ value.id+'"> </a>
```

Comment: Put `callB(id)` in the `success` function of `callA()`.

Comment: On the `load` event you want to call `callA` followed by `callB`. Do I have this right? Can you move both functions out of the event handler, then put the call to `callB` into the success handler for `callA`?

Comment: @superJumbo as `callA` completes I need `callb` to fire, that is correct. I previously had it in the success call but it would not let me use a function in there. I can try again although the same question remains, how to pass the variable?

Comment: @barmar thanks. When I literally add the function `callb` just before the closing `}` of the Success of A, it prevents anything from being done with `callb`. It just ignores it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What will make your life easier, is that you can define a function in one place, then call it later from another place. You don't need to define your functions inside an `if` block, or even inside your `document.load` callback. You can define your functions at the top-most level of your script.

A simplified example:

```js
function callA() {
 // ... code ...
}

function callB() {
 // ... code ...
}

jQuery(document).on('popup/show', (event, id) => {
  // you can run callA and/or callB however you want
});
```

If you want to run callA, which makes an AJAX call, then get some data and pass it to callB, you'll want to use the callback pattern like this:

```js
function callA(callback) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    // ... ajax options ...
    success: function(data) {
      var id = jQuery().data('id');
      // you can pass functions as arguments to other functions! :)
      callback(id);
    }
  });
}

function callB(id) {
  // ... use 'id' here ...
}

jQuery(document).on('popup/show', (event, id) => {
  // pass callB as the callback to callA
  // callB will run after in callA's ajax success method
  callA(callB);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much this makes a lot of sense. Is there an advantage to this way over having them all together?

Comment: np! The main advantage to having them this way is if you want to re-use the functions in different scenarios -- however, if you're never going to re-use the function in a different case, then you can just keep all the relevant code together in one function

Comment: got it. That is what I thought but wanted to confirm. Thanks! I wish I could accept both of yours as the answers

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is asynchronous, so you're calling `callB()` before the AJAX call in `callA()` has completed.

In order to use the `id` variable in `callA()`, you need to call `callB()` from within the `callA()` success function.

```
jQuery(document).on('popup/show', (event, id) => {
  if (id === 123) {
    function callA() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        data: {
          action: 'list_count'
        },
        type: 'post',
        url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
          var id = jQuery().data('id')
          var html = '';

          jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
            html += '<div class="accordion-header ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-corner-all" id="' + value.id + '" style="display:table-row">';
            html += '<div class="image"  style="display: table-cell";>' + value.img + '</div>';
            html += '<div style="display: table-cell";>' + value.Name + '</div>';
            html += '<div  style="display: table-cell">' + value.Size + '</div>';
            html += '<div  style="display: table-cell"> ' + value.Number + ' </div>';
            html += '<div class="tdid_' + value.id + '"  style="display: table-cell">' + value.Status + '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div id="cid_' + value.id + '" class="bg_clear ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="display: table-cell">';
            html += '<div class="bg_clear ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="display: table-cell"></div>';
            html += '  </div>';
          });
          jQuery('#list').html(html);
          callB(id);
        }
      });
    }

    function callB(id) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
        data: {
          action: 'options_function',
          cid: id
        },
        success: function(data) {
          jQuery(data).after('#cid_' + id)
          console.log(data);
          console.log(id);
        }
      });
    }

    callA();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I am going to play with this for a few minutes but on a quick glance, using this causes nothing to load, neither a nor b. I might have done something wrong though so I am going to check

Comment: I forgot the `id` argument to `callB()`.

Comment: You have two `id` variables, the `id` argument to the event handler, and `var id = jQuery().data('id');`. I assumed the one you want to use with `callB()` is the second one.

Comment: Ok so when I use this and check the console the first neither the first nor second ajax call are registering at all in the console. I see the `my_ajax.ajax_url,` but then the headers, request and response tabs are all blank. Simply nothing inside which leads me to believe it isnt running at all. I removed the top `id` variable

Comment: If it weren't running you wouldn't see the URL, either. I've never seen it with empty headers tab.

Comment: And I didn't change how `callA()` is called, so that should work the same as before.

Comment: Yea I know thats why I am confused. I am working through it with the alert. I also tried the method above and have the same issue. I am about to put a settime in it in case its loading too fast. But on the answer above I asked for an alert just after the function is called but before the ajax. It works. When I ask for it as the first line in the `success` then nothing. I am going to try it with your code too but wanted to respond to you since youre trying to be so helpful

Comment: If you're not getting the alert in the success function, it means the server isn't responding to the AJAX request.

Comment: Ok got it fixed up. Now, it doesnt seem to be passing the ID in the same way the button was however. I realize that I probably didnt give enough information so I am amending the OP to have the button code that was being used to make the initial call for `function b`. I am getting an error to move function b to the body root since there are no inner declarations.

Comment: Should also add that right after `function callB(id)` I added ` console.log(id);` which is giving me an undefined in the console. So I think that there is an issue in ` var id = jQuery().data('+id_In_Restaurant+')` near the top of `callA` . Is this not the correct way to retrieve that data piece? It comes back as an array and a string of objects which is why I was using `jquery.each()` further down

Comment: I've never seen that use of `.data()` before. Normally it's `$("selector").data("name")`. This gets the data that you saved earlier with `$("selector").data("name", value)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227309/discussion-between-barmar-and-user14955679).